# How to setting CName forwarded to App Engine private subdomain?

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain, cname

I have an app engine running on www.xyz.com and its support wildcard domain.
I have a plan to share my app, so my client will have their own sub domain example client1.xyz.com
How do I, setting CNAME on my client private domain (for example. client1.com ) to be able to forward/aliase on client1.xyz.com

I have googling but still not found solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user needs to set up a Google Apps account (or you need to set up one on their behalf) for the domain, and add your app to the account under the subdomain they want to use. This doesn't require admin permissions on your app.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your answer, I'll try it and update the result here.

Comment: I have a Google error 404.  
Step to produce is:  
(1). Setup App Engine wildcard domain on xyz.com and myclient app available on client1.xyz.com  
(2). Register Google App accout for my client's domain client1.com  
(3). Setup CName on www.client1.com to client1.xyz.com

Comment: @Ryan You need to add the App Engine app to the client's Google Apps account. Have you followed all the steps in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have change CNAME on client1.com to ghs.google.com and resolved!